# Chrome equivalent of Firefox Firebug CSS select path

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, path, selector

I've made the move to Chrome, but one of the most annoying features with 'Firebug lite' is that it doesn't allow you to copy the CSS path of objects.

To see what I mean, in Firefox, go to google.com and inspect the logo with Firebug. Right click on the 'hplogo' div and pick 'Copy CSS path'. You'll get something like:

```
html body#gsr div#main span#body.ctr-p center div#lga div div#hplogo
```

This is an incredibly useful feature that I can't find on Chrome, it appears you can only copy the Xpath.

Is there a way to use this type of functionality in Chrome?

Thanks

Comment: "incredibly useful" ...how so?

Comment: Just a note - check the reviews of the app in the app store. Several posters mention issues with being able to copy the XPath and CSSPath. I'm a Mac user, just installed the app, was happy to see pathing, and sad to be unable to copy the path. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: that's why I haven't switched to Chrome yet myself

Comment: this is indeed a big minus for chrome. @wdm it is incredibly useful, when you have to change big websites that you did not build and you have very little time in firefox you just copy the selector and make the changes, you don't have to lose time trying to understand everything that is in the website.

Comment: @Claudiu sounds more like it's supporting bad habits, especially if you're using a css preprocessor such as LESS or Sass. The next person to come along is going to have to understand what css rules you hacked on top of the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no native way to get this information in Chrome. You can do a bunch of hacks, using jQuery and bookmarks as show here: http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/chrome/tip-copy-css-selector-in-chrome/ as well as here: http://www.selectorgadget.com/

However, you may find this extension to be closer to what you want, and a little easier to use: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lbghbpofdlcecfbpjgmffnkieenjkboi
It will pull the XPath as well as the CSS Path, and allow you to easily copy the text.

Answer (score 6):

In chrome you can right click on an element in the elements explorer view and select copy CSS path or copy Xpath.