# Google Chrome copy CSS Path in Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, web-developer-toolbar

Google Chrome's Developer Tools shows the CSS path (or a large portion of it) of the selected element at the bottom of the toolbar. In Firebug, you are able to right-click on any selector in the the CSS Path, and grab the CSS Path up to that element. Does Google Chrome have this feature? What tools are available if there is no built-in support?

[image: Chrome CSS Path]

Comment: Possibily this is the answer 

[Chrome copy csspath][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292794/css-query-generation-apis/22344323#22344323

Comment: That gives just enough of the path for it to be a unique element, but I was more looking for the entire CSS Path. Thanks though!

Comment: Correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35412554/242933

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Chrome has updated this option**

In chrome after recent update this option has been changed from
`(right click on the element in Elements Window) > Copy CSS path`
to :
`(right click on the element in Elements Window) > Copy > Copy selector`

Answer (score 6):

Chrome doesn't have it, so people have made chrome extensions, bookmarklets, and other tools for Chrome to replicate this functionality.

Possible duplicate:
[Chrome equivalent of Firefox Firebug CSS select path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443437/chrome-equivalent-of-firefox-firebug-css-select-path)

Bookmarklet:
http://www.selectorgadget.com/

Chrome Extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lbghbpofdlcecfbpjgmffnkieenjkboi

I would still like other people's answers, suggestions, and tips on how to best deal with this in Chrome.

Comment: I agree, it would be ideal to be able to just copy it, since it is built already, and they also offer the ability to copy xpath and html from the same place. It's quite silly to require an extension for this.

Comment: "Or, I could just learn to Google better". I've lost count of the number of times I've searched Google for help with a programming related problem, only to find dismissive QA replies like "Learn to use Google". Thank you for also including a helpful answer :)

Answer (score 6):

You can right click on the element in the main source window and "Copy CSS path". This has been a life saver when I have to work on pages that I can't re-code.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: The OP (any myself) are looking for the longer path than what is offered by "Copy CSS path" (See the bottom of the image posted)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small (CoffeeScript) snippet that will give CSS path (up to first id element - though you can easily change that by removing the break part):

```
getCSSPath = (node)->
  parts = []
  while node.parentElement
    str = node.tagName
    if node.id
      str += "##{node.id}"
      parts.unshift str
      break
    siblingsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(node.parentElement.childNodes)
    ind = siblingsArr.filter((n)-> n.attributes?).indexOf(node)
    parts.unshift str + ":nth-child(#{ind + 1})"
    node = node.parentElement
  parts.join ' > '
```

Uses ":nth-child" for every node, so you need to modify it if you'd like to get also class names.