# Is there a way to copy the path that appears in Chrome's dev tools after Inspecting an Element?

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom

When you select `Inspect Element` with Chrome, at the bottom of the Developer's panel, a path to that element is shown.

[image]

In this instance, it was `body > div#divsinglecolumnwidth.singlecolumnwidth > div#productdescription>h2`.

Is there a way to copy that "path"?

Answer (score 9):

When you select an element in the DOM inspector, that element becomes $0 in the console:

> "Use $0 in the console to refer this element"

So you can simply go to the console and paste the following:

```
crumb = function(node) {
var idOrClass = (node.id && "#"+node.id) || (""+node.classList && (" "+node.classList).replace(/ /g, "."));
return node.tagName.toLowerCase() + idOrClass;};
crumbPath = function(node) {return node.parentNode ? crumbPath(node.parentNode).concat(crumb(node)) : [];};
crumbPath($0);
```

The output looks like this:

```
["html", "body.question-page.new-topbar", "div.container._full.", "div#content", "div", "div.inner-content.clearfix", "div#mainbar", "div#question", "div.post-layout", "div.postcell.post-layout--right", "div.post-text", "p"]
```

[Source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/WeRo8aijpYc/IlnGmFa3k3gJ)

Comment: Indeed this works though for an element inside an iframe within a page, this solution seems to just find the path till the html node inside the iframe. So to workaround this, I had to execute it twice to get the complete path. Once till the iframe as $0 and then again for the element inside the iframe as $0.

Comment:  Thanks for that solution!  Great for **CSS specificity debugging**! A compact xPath shows the ID if possible and a full xPath shows the elements along the path, but not their classes/IDs. Whereas your **crumb path** shows all elements with all their classes and IDs along the path. A great auxiliary tool to determine/debug why a CSS selector matches a particular element on website/webpage/user/mode 1 but not on 2 or X!

Answer (score 5):

You can open the Inspector, and select the DOM node as displayed in this picture:

[image: 1]

Do a **right-click** > **copy** > **copy Selector**

You'll get the specific path (just like the one you needed) in case you want to do something in CSS (or other) with that element.

Answer (score 3):

Just right click on the DOM node, and select `Copy xPath` option.

You'll get a standard xPath looking like this: `//*[@id="copyright"]/a[1]`

Comment: I wish that was also possible for CSS definitions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369895/google-chrome-copy-css-path-in-developer-tools

Comment: Unfortunately, the xPath doesn't include the full path that shows in the bottom bar (not spelled out anyway). I was hoping to have a way of copying that entire path, everything from <body> to the element I inspected. Everything that shows in the dev panel.

Comment: can't believe this does not exist