# CSS query generation APIs

Tags: firefox-addon, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

I have had enough search on this topic and could not find a suitable answer, finally my question is Does any one know any APIs which I can use to generate CSS query from the web page, similar to the Xpath we get it from Mozilla or chrome plugins.

attached is the image for reference.

[image: Similar to copyXpath]

On the similar lines of this image, I need API for CSSQuery which gives me CSS query for selected element

Comment: Why did you add the Java tag? Did you mean: [tag:JavaScript]?

Comment: @RobW : just wanted to explore if any Java guy knows any java-APIs.

Comment: @chaosguru: UI controls are not APIs :) Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov :How JQuery is an API then :) I mean has a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally wrote my own code which generates a perfect css query :-)

Comment: Can you share please it would be very useful to us.

Comment: I have written I chrome extension which can be used, Will share with you. meanwhile you can try with chrome native API as shown above

Comment: Thanks looking forward to it. The above gets only xpath though right?

Comment: nope, its Copy CSS Path as well, if you check properly

Comment: Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369895/google-chrome-copy-css-path-in-developer-tools/28368127#28368127

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector), [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) (and their counterparts for `Element`)?

Comment: I have updated the question with image . hope it will be more clear.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. Well, unlike XPath, there's no unique CSS selector for an element in the general case. If you have a specific suggestion for how this should work, feel free to file a feature request at http://crbug.com/new!

Comment: Hi @Alexander : thank you for your reply. :-) I will do the same

Answer (score 0):

Atlast the CopyCssPath is implemented by Chrome
 [image: CopyCSSPath from Chromium]