# Get only class/id names when "copy css path" in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, css-selectors, developer-tools

When i rightclick in Chrome dev tools on an element and try to copy the css path of something i get something like this:

```
body > div > div > div > div > div.span3 > aside > div:nth-child(1)
```

For (re)writing CSS this would be very usefull if it would only show the class or id names instead of the DOM element or the # of the child element.

Does anyone know of a plugin or something which gives you more control over this feature?

Comment: If the element has an ID, then you will in fact obtain just the ID of the element, given the nature of IDs. The problem is that "Copy CSS path" constructs a selector that *only* the selected element will match, something that a class selector alone cannot accomplish (but an ID should, theoretically).

Comment: Hmm.. i'm actually not that much of an expert on the developer tools.. but in order to structure my css accordingly it's important that I use relative paths so i select just that element that i need to select. I taught that the 'CSS path' feature would be of great help of obtaining the relative path, because these paths can become quite long in big websites.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome copy CSS Path in Developer Tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369895/google-chrome-copy-css-path-in-developer-tools)