# Safari equivalent of Chrome copy CSS path

Tags: google-chrome, safari

I need to get css path of some elements in Safari, and as we all know, we can right click on an element in the elements explorer view and select copy CSS path in Chrome as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443437/chrome-equivalent-of-firefox-firebug-css-select-path) said, but can Safari(or some Safari extensions) do this?
Thx